# Does "should" imply an opinion?

Tags: meaning, conditionals

If I am given a short story about a situation. Then at the end I am asked:

> Should this person complete task A?

Does that imply that I have to give my opinion and support it from points in the short story?

I believe it does imply an opinion.

---

The short story has been intentionally left out, so that we only focus on the implications of the word *should*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the story and the context of the question.

If the story presents the person with an ethical dilemma, the answer to the question would likely be based on your opinion of the appropriate response. For instance, the story might be about an employee who has been given a task that might not be considered ethical, such as getting information from a friend who works for a competitor. There is no clear answer to this type of question, you can only answer based on your personal moral code.

But if the situation is less ethically charged, the question may be answered objectively. If the story were about a person who made a commitment to perform a task, and you were asked whether he should complete the task, the answer would clearly be yes.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, should can imply an *obligation* or a *possibility*.

When should implies an obligation, it means this person should complete the task because it's his/her duty. But the obligation is not strong enough to punish the person for not fulfilling it. In your example, the person won't be punished if he/she doesn't complete the task

Should can also imply a possibility in your example. If there are other tasks to complete, or other people to complete the task you can use should to indicate it. For example?

> Should this person complete task A (or should he/she complete task B)?

or

> Should this person complete task A (or should the other person complete task A)?

Comment: It can also indicate a conditional case..."Should he finish his current task, then give him this new task."